# Designing Hotspot in linux with additional features

Tags: php, linux, network-programming, cgi, firewall

I am doing my B.tech Major project and designing a hotspot s/w for linux server . It includes following features :
1. **Bandwidth monitoring** : I have to monitor how much bandwidth a particular user is using.I have taken help for this from  [Easy Hot spot](http://easyhotspot.inov.asia/index.php/documentation).

1. Block the particular Website to the user
2. Keep Tracking of the log on the user side  : It shows which websites user have accessed and what data he has uploaded on which website.

First feature I have done using Free Radius and chilliSpot but I need your help for remaining two that which technology I should use for the remaining features?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For blocking, you can just add their IP to iptables.

```
# drop any packets from this guy.
iptables -A INPUT --src 99.99.99.99 -j DROP
# Change the -A to a -D to delete
```

For tracking data, you could use iptables too, but that might be too low level. Instead, you could have iptables re-direct their packets to a transparent squid/varnish/whatever proxy. The proxy can do the logging.

```
# transparent redirect all NAT traffic to our local squid proxy on 8080.
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING --src 99.99.99.99 -p tcp -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8080
```

Comment: I don't want to drop packet from a particular guy instead i want to block the packet for a particular website e.g. If http://www.facebook.com is blocked now one should be able to use facebook .